Misère Fibonacci Nim winning strategy
I'm looking for any info about winning strategies at misère Fibonacci Nim. I know the answer for the normal play, but it seems like nobody talks about the misère play. Does anyone have references about this problem?
Thx
Edit: I'm talking about Fibonacci Nim, not Nim. That is, only one pile of stones, and you can remove up to twice as much stones as did your opponent on the previous turn. The winning strategy uses Zeckendorf expansion and exists iff the number of stones is not a Fibonacci number.
Edit 2: In the misère form of this game one also forbids to take off all but one stone at first move, otherwise the game would be a trivial win for first player.

The misere variant has almost the same strategy as the usual convention -- until the regular strategy would leave a pile (or piles) having only one element (each).  Then the strategy reverses.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222059/misere-nim-variant

@EricTowers, what you describe works for Nim and the octal game described at that link, but for "Fibonacci Nim", the game mentioned in this question, I don't believe even the normal-play strategy is known for multiple piles.

@EricTowers I edited the question to make it clearer, Mark S. is right.

On the first move of Fibonacci nim with just one pile of stones the first player can remove any number of stones up to one less than the number of stones in the pile.  If the first player  does exactly that in misère play, then the second player has to remove the remaining stone and loses.  You'll therefore need to further modify the rules to make the misère game interesting.  If you modify them so that the first player must leave at least two stones then I think the misère version will be equivalent to the normal version with one stone fewer.

@lonzaleggiera Yes, of course, we need to not allow to take all but one stones at first move. I tried, without success, to explore by myself some ideas like yours, I'll look for this one specifically, thank you for advice.
